# Implementing Local Notifications in Xamarin.Forms using Xam.Plugins.Notifier

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-notifications

i have implemented Local Notifications in Xamarin.Forms using Xam.Plugins.Notifier. I have added the Nuget Package in PCL, iOS and Android. 
below code is displaying the notification. i wrote the below chunk of code in my PCL

CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("test" + "  " + " New test", "Some Notification", 5,DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(8));

I have added the below code in AppDelegate.CS

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
        {
            // iOS 10.0+
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(
                UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
                (approved, error) => { });

            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new UserNotificationCenterDelegate();
        }
```

I am able to get the notification in iOS but am not getting the notification in Android. Do i need add any code in MainActivity.cs
can someone help me to fix this?

FYI: https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin

Comment: To receive notification by Android project you need create a receiver in the android manifest, at least using Firebase

Answer (score 1):

As the document said, your code :

```
CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("test" + " " + " New test", "Some Notification", 5, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(8));
```

It will display a local notification at a scheduled date/time,  your notification will display after 8s delay.

If you want display a local notification immediately, you could try using :

```
CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("title", "body");
```

It works fine on my side.

Update :

You were missing something to display a notification  .

As per the official documentation: 
 a [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) object must contain the following:

1. A small icon, set by [SetSmallIcon()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int))
2. A title, set by [SetContentTitle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentTitle(java.lang.CharSequence))
3. Detail text, set by [SetContentText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentText(java.lang.CharSequence))

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I wantedly made it for 8sec. My problem is the notifications are not firing up in Android. Do i need to write any code in MainActivity.cs like i wrote it for AppDelegate.CS? Can you please help me out.

Comment: When i debug it am getting this exception. Its coming in android only not in iOS.
{System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.   at Plugin.LocalNotifications.CrossLocalNotifications.get_Current () [0x00012] in <ff7ca4d01a15447e8f98d1c69ca4c994>:0    at

Comment: @SanthoshKumar, please post the complete error message.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar, and how did you use the `CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show` method ? please post your complete code.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply again. I missed to add the nuget package for Droid Project. now the notifications are firing up. One question here. Why it is not asking for the Request to Allow or Don't allow Pop up to display the notifications like how iOS app asks it

Comment: Even it is not showing the toast in the app. When i launch the notification bar from the top then i can ale to see the notifications. Do we need to add any code to get this ?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar, actually the Push Notification permission lie in Normal Category Permission  not in Dangerous Category Permission, so you could directly use it.

Comment: Okay. But how to display the toast in the app in the top, rather than pulling the notification bar and see it ? how to achieve this?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar, you could refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949501/android-show-notification-with-a-popup-on-top-of-any-application

Comment: @ York Shen,  I wrote the below code in MainActivity.cs but its not showing up

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            builder.SetContentTitle("VLOnMobile")
                   .SetContentInfo("Licenses are Going to Expire")
                   .SetPriority((NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh));
                    
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            mNotificationManager.Notify(0, builder.Build());

Comment: @SanthoshKumar, I have update my answer, you may check it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wrote the below code, they are coming but not showing as Toast
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            builder.SetContentTitle("VLOnMobile")
                   .SetContentInfo("Licenses are Going to Expire")
                   .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                   .SetContentText("Hello World!")
                   .SetPriority((NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh));

Comment: NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            mNotificationManager.Notify(0, builder.Build());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160767/discussion-between-york-shen-msft-and-santhosh-kumar).

Comment: @SanthoshKumar, you could open a new question for a better solution. : )

Comment: Can you come to chat?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar, could you please mark it as an answer ?