# How to show something on Incoming Call Screen under Delphi 10.2

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

The problem here often appeared, but I didn't found anything about it for delphi and firemonkey.

I would like to display some information when my application detects an incoming call (Android).
I know it would be best to create my own phone application and set it as the default one. 
But Android has Toas and Notification and I thought to use it.

1) I tried to use a toast but did not manage to display information **ON THE** incoming call screen

2) Notification displays the message but I must first swipe down notification bar. It gives me nothing. I would like information to appear for example like
information about the end of the battery (information available above all screen application)

Is anyone able to tell me something?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top / https://stackoverflow.com/q/9656185/80901

Comment: Yes, these are similar topics, but all for the android studio. I need instructions for Delphi. This is what I am looking for, but also for the android studio:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949501/android-show-notification-with-a-popup-on-top-of-any-application or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683952/pop-up-window-over-android-native-incoming-call-screen-like-true-caller-android?rq=1

Comment: @Olaf obviously, you would have to use the same Android APIs, just translate the Java code into Delphi code. There are numerous online tutorials and StackOverflow questions that show how to use Android APIs in Delphi using Embarcadero's JNIBridge framework.

Comment: Thanks @remy. I will try.

Comment: Might help to show what you've tried so far, as well

Comment: Sure @Dave, please. I will be grateful !

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my comment - it would be helpful if *you* show what *you* have tried so far. I may help to complete it

Comment: OK. So far I'll read about JNIBridge. I've never worked in JAVA so I need some time