# make flutter notification (via firebase) pop to foreground (and not to be only icon in statusbar)

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am trying to implement notifications for a flutter app.

On iPhone (left) it looks like expected and the notification is show for a short time, then hides automatically.

But on Android (right side, Android 9, motorola) it appears just as an icon in the status bar.
[image]
How can i make it pop up? Right now I have to swipe down on it to see the contents.

The notification is send via Firebase with their [PHP-Sdk](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cloud-messaging.html).

```php
$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile('....');

$firebase = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount);
$messaging = $firebase->createMessaging();

$title = 'Test Titel '.date('YmdHis');
$body = 'Meine Nachricht '.date('YmdHis');
$colkey = 'newmessagtenoti';
$count = 23;

$message = new RawMessageFromArray([
        'notification' => [
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#notification
            'title' => $title,
            'body' => $body,
        ],
        'data' => [
            'key_1' => 'Value 1',
            'key_2' => 'Value 2',
        ],

        'android' => [
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#androidconfig
            'ttl' => '3600s',
            'priority' => 'high',
            "collapse_key"=> $colkey,

            'notification' => [
                'notification_priority' => 'PRIORITY_MAX',
                'visibility' => 'PUBLIC',
                'title' => $title,
                'body' => $body,
                'notification_count' => $count,
            ],
        ],
        'apns' => [
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#apnsconfig
            'headers' => [
                'apns-priority' => '10',
            ],
            'payload' => [
                'aps' => [
                    'alert' => [
                        'title' => $title,
                        'body' => $body,
                    ],
                    'badge' => $count,
                    'apns-collapse-id' =>  $colkey,
                ],
            ],
        ],

    ]);

// $firebase->getMessaging()->send($message);
$report = $messaging->sendMulticast($message, $deviceTokens);

echo 'Successful sends: '.$report->successes()->count().PHP_EOL;
echo 'Failed sends: '.$report->failures()->count().PHP_EOL;

if ($report->hasFailures()) {
    foreach ($report->failures()->getItems() as $failure) {
        echo $failure->error()->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

I read all [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) but even with high priority it does not get bigger.

I guess i am missing something in the code for Android. Maybe in "AndroidManifest.xml"?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flut7_push">

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="flut7_push"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>            
        </activity>       

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I have the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking into how to get a [heads-up notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#Heads-up) on Android.

I would suggest to use [FCM's "Data message"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) and then handle it at your `FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived` implementation and then play there with priority/importance as it explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29949603/3090951).